# Mouseout for infoWindow.close doesn't work on Google Maps v3 in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I have an event listener on 'mouseover' that work and shows the correct text in the infoWindow however these infoWindow's never go away unless you press the x. I want them to disappear after the user moves their mouse away. Below is the code.

Thanks!

```
iPark.makeMarker = function (lat, long, street, location, description ) {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long)
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    title: 'Click to Zoom'
  });
  marker.setMap(this.map)

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    iPark.map.setZoom(18);
    iPark.map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      iPark.map.setZoom(13)
      iPark.map.setCenter(37.7833, -122.4167)
    })
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
    iPark.infoWindow(street).open(iPark.map, marker)
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
    console.log("hello")
    iPark.closeinfoWindow
  });
}

iPark.infoWindow = function(street){
  return new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: String(street)
})

iPark.closeinfoWindow = InfoWindow.close()

};
```

Comment: Do you have a fiddle that shows the problem?

Answer (score 4):

Store the infoWindow as a property of the marker:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
    if(!this.get('iw'))this.set('iw',iPark.infoWindow(street));
    this.get('iw').open(iPark.map, this);
  });
```

then you'll be able to access it later:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
    this.get('iw').close();
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I actually was able to make iPark.infoWindow a global variable and that solved the problem by forcing the older window to disappear when I called a new window on the new marker.

Comment: Thanks, Dr.Molle, this sorted it out for me. I have many markers on the page, and each one now has a reference to it's own infowindow which it can now close.

Answer (score 0):

This looks wrong.

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
    console.log("hello")
    iPark.closeinfoWindow
  });
```

This might work better (not tested, based off the reported working "mouseout" function):

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
    iPark.infoWindow(street).close();

  });
```